# Is there any CFG available (with pos tags -part of speech tags) to validate the grammar of sentences in english?

Tags: nlp, nltk, computer-science, automata

It may not be 100 % accurate but still is there any written and tested CFG.
is it available with nltk data?

Comment: Asking for links to resources is explicitly discouraged in the [help]. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: the first problem here is that even native speakers will not always agree whether a sentence is grammatical or nor. how's the computer supposed to do it?

Comment: No CFG can be 100% accurate since English is at least context-sensitive, if not Turing complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer: no. Long answer: noooooooooooooo

This is a huge issue. One CFG couldn't possibly come even close to the complexity that English presents. Even the POS taggers aren't terribly accurate.

The very best spelling and grammar checkers look for invariant laws of English and violations therein. Search for English grammar rules and think about how you might use software to detect them.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#y). And search for the word "probability". There are options for printing the probability of parse trees and you can interpret them as confidence, etc.